# How to aggregate build status of multie Jenkins jobs that run HP performance centre script

Tags: performance, jenkins, continuous-integration, center, devops

I have almost 50 freestyle Jenkins builds that run as many performance centre tests everyday morning and evening. Currently I am getting status of these individual runs on email but would like to consolidate the results in one e-mail. Now problem with this is output of Jenkins build is always pass when it is able to run pc tests. To find actual result I need to see the artifact that contains HTML result. Is there a way I can read these individual HTML output and group them in one report. Like
           Dev   test prod
Test1 pass fails pass
Test2 fail    pass pass
Test3 pass pass pass
 I have little programming or scripting exp so pls forgive me for not using much resources on my own

Answer (score 0):

You may use [build result trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) to monitor as many jobs required. For consolidating use tutorial [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/)

Comment: Hi Sachin, I have tried build result trigger plugin but that didn't help my cause. Artifact that I need to verify are in being saved in artifact directory in HTML format which I need to read and check status for each build. I think some custom script may help but I lack exp to write such a script.